# Rebuilding an app in Dokku results in 'ERROR: Failed to download minimal PHP for bootstrapping!'

Tags: php, heroku

I'm using Dokku for over a year now, most of the programs are written in node.js. But for a Wordpress blog we use the default heroku PHP buildpack.

After a system upgrade and subsequent reboot our blog failed to rebuild.

Right now I'm greeted with the following error

```
-----> PHP app detected
-----> Bootstrapping...

 !     ERROR: Failed to download minimal PHP for bootstrapping!
 !     
 !     This is most likely a temporary internal error. If the problem
 !     persists, make sure that you are not running a custom or forked
 !     version of the Heroku PHP buildpack which may need updating.
```

I've tried to use `dokku trace on` but this does not give extra output near this error. I don't get why the error occurs, it seems as if it's just the curl command that fails. But the S3 bucket itself is available from the host machine and Dokku does not show me the actual URL it's trying to fetch.

What's the best way to find why this is failing and how do I resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

So after another day of tinkering the following became clear:

- After the update to the latest Ubuntu version, the file `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/dokku.list` had it's only line (referring to the dokku repository) commented.
- I uncommented the line without reading properly.

After careful readying the line in the `dokku.list` file read:

```
deb https://packagecloud.io/dokku/dokku/ubuntu/ trusty main
```

instead of:

```
deb https://packagecloud.io/dokku/dokku/ubuntu/ xenial main
```

or:

```
deb https://packagecloud.io/dokku/dokku/ubuntu/ bionic main
```

Presumably it failed to change after I updated from trusty to xenial. And since it wasn't up-to-date in xenial it failed to update itself when upgrading to byonic.

After fixing this the `apt update` command gave me 1 package that could be upgraded: `herokuish`

Upgrading this package pulled the latest docker image and enabled me to rebuild the wordpress without issues.